# Can I keep derived state in state in React if memoization is not efficient?

Tags: reactjs, state

### Summary

I pass a prop to a child component. This prop is calculated from the state of the parent component. However, computing the prop from scratch at every render is wasteful. Memoization does not work so well either. The most efficient way to keep that prop up-to-date is to keep it as another state in the parent component and update it on certain events. My concern is that React does not recommend keeping "derived state" in the state. I'm trying to find "the right way" of solving this problem.

### Question

The official [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) walks you through building a Tic-Tac-Toe app. The tutorial stores the whole board for each move:

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  state = {
    history: [
      {
        squares: Array(9).fill(null)
      }
    ],
    stepNumber: 0,
    xIsNext: true,
  }
  // More code here
}
```

I thought that this is very wasteful and realized that I can simply store the square indices in an array as:

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  state = {
    moves: [],
    stepNumber: 0,
  }
  // More code here
}
```

`moves` would contain the square indices made by both players. Even indices (0th, 2nd, 4th, etc.) would contain `X`'s moves and odd indices would contain `O`'s moves.

Using `moves` and `stepNumber`, current board can be calculated like:

```
static getSquares(moves, stepNumber) {
  const squares = Array(9).fill(null);
  moves = moves.slice(0, stepNumber);
  for (let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
    squares[moves[i]] = i % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
  }
  return squares;
}
```

I know that this is not a very wasteful calculation but still, had we kept `squares` in the state, we could have simply edited a single element of `squares` each time a new move is played:

```
addMove = move => {
  this.setState( ({moves, stepNumber, squares}) => {
    moves = moves.slice(0, stepNumber);
    if (moves.includes(move)) return;
    squares[move] = stepNumber % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
    stepNumber++;
    moves.push(move);
    return {
      moves,
      stepNumber,
      squares,
    }
  });
}
```

This way, we simply change a single element of squares. This is much more efficient than calculating the whole board from scratch at each render. Similar idea goes for another event named `jumpTo`.

AFAICT, memoization would not work here either because we are using the previous state of `squares` to calculate its next state.

So, even though `squares` is technically derived state and React does not recommend keeping derived state in the state, I couldn't find a more efficient way to calculate it without treating it as state, since the most efficient way to calculate it makes use of previous version of it.

My question is, what is "the right way" to solve this?

Comment: Is it hampering your realtime performance of the App?

Comment: @PrateekThapa Doesn't matter. It is an example. Had it something else that hampered the performance, I want to know what is the right way to implement it, while keeping the efficient update algorithm on `squares` that I currently have.